# How to calculate CPU Load in android programmatically?

Tags: android, performance, cpu-usage

I have checked various examples and questions here, but what I am getting is android CPU Usage, but not CPU load.
Also, while doing some R&D on android CPU I came to know that CPU load could be calculated as a sum of **android tasks running + tasks waiting (for cores) + tasks blocked** but again I am not able to find how to get number of these tasks.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try running `top` and reading `/proc/stat`

Comment: I did tried them, but they return an array of int values which gives is CPU stats in this order... user, system, idle and other cpu usage in percentage.
I am really not getting if I am understanding it right or not, is there any tutorial which can explain what these commands return in detail?
Also, I wanted to find CPU load, not usage

Comment: `/proc/stat` gives you idle cpu time, so if you can read this file, read between two timestamps (suppose 1000 ms between reads), measure the idle time (suppose it was 200 ms) and you'll have 80% load for the measured second

Comment: for reference, you can look for `man proc` and `procfs`

Comment: I appreciate your help @nandsito but the thing is I am pretty new in this concept, so I am really not getting it.. can u show  me with some code example please?

Comment: if you think my suggestion is promising, investigate it further and ask another question if you get stuck